# Using ReactJS and normal javascript code together

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to work with React. I got a HTML page with some contents and a corresponding JS script holding the logic. Now I decided to use React to dynamically create some reusable view components within a button click event.

Simple example:

HTML

```
<script src="/ReactTester/react/react.js"></script>
<script src="/ReactTester/react/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>

<script src="/ReactTester/myreact.js" type="text/babel"></script>

<button onclick="button_click()">Button</button>
<div id="example"></div>
```

React + JS

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass(
{
    render: function() 
    {
        return(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>);
    }
});

var button_click = function ()
{
    ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld/>, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

When I click the button I get the error

```
ReferenceError: 'button_click' is not defined
```

If I try to render the element without using the button event everything works fine. It seems to be a problem with mixing React and normal JS code. Am I missing something? What's wrong?

Any hint would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you rendering that page? Off the filesystem our via some http server?

Comment: via Tomcat instance. It's a eclipse project, deployed as .war

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        );
    }
});

var button_click = function () {
    ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('example'));
}

document.getElementByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', button_click);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `button_click` function defined in your  file is not available in  the global scope. If you attach to the global scope via the `window` object for example : `window.button_click = ...` that will work. But explicitly attaching the event handler as stated in the  other answer is a better option since there is no global scope pollution.